# Can you use Javascript to put date/time into form input onload?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to put the date and time into a form field onload.  Am I doing something wrong here, I can't get it to work.  Here is my code:

```
<HEAD>
<script type="text/javascript">
            function updateData()
            {
                var cl_dt=new Date();
                document.getElementByName("lastpost_cl").value=cl_dt;
            }
</script>
</HEAD>

<BODY onLoad="updateData();">

<form id="FormName" action="updated.php" method="post" name="FormName">
<input id="lastpost_cl" name="lastpost_cl" type="text" size="25" maxlength="255">
```

Comment: Why not just use jQuery? In the '$(document).ready' jQuery function just set the default value like '$("#lastpost_cl").val = new Date();'.

Will handle it easier.

Comment: Just a footnote: Don't use uppercase tag names like `<BODY>` and `<HEAD>`, nor camel case attributes like `onLoad` - stick with lower case all the way. Also, if this is the full scope of what you're trying to do don't bother with jQuery; it would be like killing an ant hill with the Stark Jericho missile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use getElementById. getElementsByName (There is an 's' after Element!) returns a collection of element(s).

Answer (score 1):

getElementByName does not exist, at least not cross browser. Use getElementById instead. You already have an ID that is the same, so it will work with just that change.